# Stability of critical point for system ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Determine the stability of $(0,0)$ for the following system
$$
 x' = Ax 
$$
where the $2 \times 2$ matrix 
$$
A = \left( \array{3 &-5 \\1 &-4} \right)
$$

Comment: thanks, but where does the (0,0) part come into it?

Answer (score 1):

This is a linear system so the Jacobian is $ J(x) = A $ for every $x$.

The eigenvalues of $J(x)$ are $\lambda_{1,2} = \frac{-1 \pm \sqrt{29}}{2} $ which have opposite sign, so there are not stable points.